# Unknown Line Above HTML GIF

Tags: html, css, image, border, gif

On my website, located at http://tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/chapter/indexa.html, I have noticed a faint line that appears above my gif robot animation (found on the red section). I have investigated borders, margins, and padding and found that none of the above are the culprit.

Any idea what this is from and how it can be prevented in general?

Comment: Zoom & check the image below, it has got black border around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its nothing to do with the css, the image itself has got a black border. Zoom & see the [image] border.

OR

```
img {
outline: 1px solid white;
outline-offset: -4px;
}
```

Reference Link: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/bNmzB/

[Adjust the outline & color accordingly, this should work for sure]

Good luck & hope this helps.

Comment: yup, not sure why it's not visible on the bottom border in your page, but it's there too.

Comment: Simply crop the images to 1px that's all.

Comment: The problem is that it is a gif with 200+ images so it is a bit impractical to edit each one. Is there a way I can crop the gif as a whole using CSS?

Comment: A work around is the css as depicted in the updated answer.